# Configure to start JMeter as systemd service

Tags: jmeter, systemd, configure, systemctl

I generally use "nohup" to start Jmeter, Instead of using Cmd all the time, i have decided to configure a systemd service which runs the Jmeter all the time.

i have this below command: which basically run the jmeter and logs the output

`nohup /app/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/jmeter -j /app/server-1/jmeter/logs/jmeter-traffic.log -n -t /app/jmeter/inputfile.jmx > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

i Have created a .service file which runs the above command on

```
ExecStart=/app/jemter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/jmeter -j /app/jmeter/logs/jmeter-log -n -t /app/jmeter/inputfile.jmx > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

when i started the service - i encountered various errors.

```
EX: class path contains multiple bindings
EX: failed to start the service
EX: failed at step EXEC spawing 
EX: an error occured at arg: >
```

Is this the correct way of starting the service or should i be creating the shell script file to include the above command.

Answer (score 0):

systemd knows nothing about your `>` operator so I would recommend leaving the command as it is:

```
ExecStart=/app/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/jmeter -j /app/jmeter/logs/jmeter-log -n -t /app/jmeter/inputfile.jmx
```

If you don't want to see JMeter output in the journal you can [amend your systemd unit configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) like:

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=journal
```

I would also suggest adding `-l` command line argument so you could store the results into a [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) for further analysis

More information: [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)